# Aviary SDK not showing up in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, aviary

I cannot seem to get the Aviary SDK to appear in Eclipse when adding it as a reference. Every other project seems to have to ability to be referenced such as; Facebook SDK, google-play-services.

I followed the instructions for installation on the website, but I was wondering if someone encountered this issue and had a fix?

Comment: hey did you solve the problem? i am too having the same problem...

Comment: No I have not. I am working on a solution. I will post when I find something.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding `project.properties` file in my Aviary-SDK project folder before adding it into eclipse.

Used this to specify that  the target API level (API level 19 in the example):

```
target=android-17
```

Used this to specify that the project is a library:

```
android.library=true
```

Hope it helps you too..